# How to extract the values of interest in a string

Tags: r, substring

In one column of my dataframe there are several namings for the same object.

Say, for example, that I'm working with types of cancer. There are several sub-specifications for each type of cancer.

```
type <- c("Breast (ER- / PR- / EGFR - / AR - / PD-L1 - / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / AR - / EGFR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 1% / FGFR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 2%)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PDL1 - / AR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 50% (Breast and IC 5% liver))", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 -)", "Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2 -)")

dat <- as.data.frame(type)
dat
```

So we have:

```
Breast (ER- / PR- / EGFR - / AR - / PD-L1 - / HER2-)                
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / AR - / EGFR -)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 1% / FGFR -)               
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 2%)                
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PDL1 - / AR -)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 50% (Breast and IC 5% liver))             
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 -)                
Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2 -)
```

It may not look like it, but we have only two different types of cancer here, which are `Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)` and `Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2-)`.

Of course I have many more rows, this is just a substract, so I would like to develop a function that allows me to count how many of each type I have, that is, paying attention to ER, PR and HER2 values.

For this, I though of creating a function that captures the string composed of `Breast (ER\s`+ `PR\s`+`HER2\s`, where `\s` is any possible value (the reason to separate them is that as you may see these three values not always follow each other).

But I didn't find a way of doing this with gsub.

Edit:

At the end I would like to get another column that would look like:

```
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)              
Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2-)
```

This would allow me to count with a `unique()` function

Comment: I would have thought the smart way to do this is to have a separate column for each tumor characteristic. That would be easier to create, and in addition would make your data much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron. I didn't create the data

Comment: Sure, I understand that. My point is that, given this data, you are not constrained to contain all these different pieces of information in a single string. You should _create_ columns to hold the pieces of information independently. For instance, have a column called `ER` which contains only the values `"Positive"`, `"Negative"` or `NA`, another column called `PR` which can have the same 3 values, etc. This will make searching and filtering your data much easier in the long run - e.g. get all the HER2+ patients would be as easy as `dat %>% filter(HER2 == "Positive")`

Comment: Such columns would be easy to create using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `stringr` package is your friend

Stringr is a package that's part of the tidyverse and provides a lot of helpful wrappers to make handling strings more intuitive.

There are a few steps needed here, so I'll show you the output after each step

```r
type <- c("Breast (ER- / PR- / EGFR - / AR - / PD-L1 - / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / AR - / EGFR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 1% / FGFR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 2%)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PDL1 - / AR -)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 50% (Breast and IC 5% liver))", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)", "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 -)", "Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2 -)")

dat <- as.data.frame(type)
intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

## Get rid of all spaces
mutate(dat, simple_type = str_remove_all(type, "[:space:]")) |> 
  pull(simple_type) # just using pull to show you where we're up to with the process
#> [1] "Breast(ER-/PR-/EGFR-/AR-/PD-L1-/HER2-)"            
#> [2] "Breast(ER-/PR-/HER2-/AR-/EGFR-)"                   
#> [3] "Breast(ER-/PR-/HER2-/BRCA-/PDL11%/FGFR-)"          
#> [4] "Breast(ER-/PR-/HER2-/BRCA-/PDL12%)"                
#> [5] "Breast(ER-/PR-/HER2-/PDL1-/AR-)"                   
#> [6] "Breast(ER-/PR-/HER2-/PD-L150%(BreastandIC5%liver))"
#> [7] "Breast(ER-/PR-/HER2-)"                             
#> [8] "Breast(ER-/PR-/HER2-/PD-L1-)"                      
#> [9] "Breast(ER-/PR+/HER2-)"

## Extract a list of the codes we're interested it
mutate(dat,
       simple_type = str_remove_all(type, "[:space:]") |>
         str_extract_all("(ER[+-])|(PR[+-])|(HER2[+-])")) |>  ## extract all instances of 'ER' and one of +/-, OR PR and one of +/-, etc.
  pull(simple_type)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR-"   "HER2-"
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] "ER-"   "PR+"   "HER2-"

## Collapse each list element into a single string, then turn the list into a character vector
### (saving this new df as 'dat' because it makes the next step much easier to write)
dat <- 
  mutate(dat,
       simple_type = str_remove_all(type, "[:space:]") |>
         str_extract_all("(ER[+-])|(PR[+-])|(HER2[+-])") |>
         lapply(str_c, collapse = " / ") |> # stringr::str_c() is pretty much identical to base::paste()
         as.character())
dat[["simple_type"]]
#> [1] "ER- / PR- / HER2-" "ER- / PR- / HER2-" "ER- / PR- / HER2-"
#> [4] "ER- / PR- / HER2-" "ER- / PR- / HER2-" "ER- / PR- / HER2-"
#> [7] "ER- / PR- / HER2-" "ER- / PR- / HER2-" "ER- / PR+ / HER2-"

## Paste back in the other stuff
dat <- mutate(dat, simple_type = str_c("Breast (", simple_type, ")"))
dat[["simple_type"]]
#> [1] "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)" "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)"
#> [3] "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)" "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)"
#> [5] "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)" "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)"
#> [7] "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)" "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)"
#> [9] "Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2-)"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If I do not missunderstand something, the cancer types can be distinguished unambiguously by +/- after "PR". Then, would this be an option for you?

Note. Probably, the way you deal with the pattern (accounting for whitespaces/typos) needs to be more advanced. I am bad in regular expressions.

```r
library(stringr)
df$type <- as.factor(str_sub(df$cancer, 14, 17))
table(df$type)
#> 
#>  PR-  PR+ 
#>    8    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Data

```
df <- data.frame(cancer = c("Breast (ER- / PR- / EGFR - / AR - / PD-L1 - / HER2-)",                
                            "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / AR - / EGFR -)",              
                            "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 1% / FGFR -)",               
                            "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 2%)",                
                            "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PDL1 - / AR -)",             
                            "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 50% (Breast and IC 5% liver))",            
                            "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)",            
                            "Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 -)",               
                            "Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2 -)")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of `stringr` approach. First, extract the ER, PR, and HER2 components, including the sign (+/-). The line starting with `across()` removes the spaces between the spaces between the texts and the sign. Then put the three components together in a column.

```
dat <- read.delim(text = text)

library(tidyverse)

dat |> 
  mutate(er = str_extract(type, "ER\\s*[+-]"),
         pr = str_extract(type, "PR\\s*[+-]"),
         her2 = str_extract(type, "HER2\\s*[+-]"),
         across(c(er, pr, her2), ~ str_remove(., "\\s")),
         type1 = paste0("Breast (", er, " / ", pr, " / ", her2, ")")) |> 
  select(-c(er, pr, her2))
 
#                                                             type                      type1
#           Breast (ER- / PR- / EGFR - / AR - / PD-L1 - / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#                     Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / AR - / EGFR -) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#          Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 1% / FGFR -) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#                   Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 2%) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#                     Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PDL1 - / AR -) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 50% (Breast and IC 5% liver)) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#                                     Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#                           Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 -) Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
#                                    Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2 -) Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2-)
```

Data:

```
text <- "type
Breast (ER- / PR- / EGFR - / AR - / PD-L1 - / HER2-)
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / AR - / EGFR -)
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 1% / FGFR -)
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / BRCA- / PDL1 2%)
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PDL1 - / AR -)
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 50% (Breast and IC 5% liver))
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2-)
Breast (ER- / PR- / HER2- / PD-L1 -)
Breast (ER- / PR+ / HER2 -)"
```